# Import file delimited to Database Column with delimiter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to import a separate CSV file per VULA.

The problem is that the file contains a column that contains a comma, so my process fails, does anyone have a solution?

The solution can be either in VB.NET or SQL

My Code

```
SELECT * FROM 
OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\8AA31234-2215-4FE4-907F-AB3B3A417F72~WO2~29302~INSTAL PP~instal pp~1319.csv',
FORMATFILE = 'C:\EMAIL\WA\FMT\COLUNAS.FMT' ) AS T
```

Comment: Are the CSV columns wrapped in quotes? That's the only way I know to handle those scenarios other than using a different delimiter. It sounds like it was generated incorrectly.

Comment: @TyCobb Yes, this is how to import without considering it as a new column?

Comment: I am asking about the `.csv` itself. Is it like this `Doe, John, 18` or is it like this: `"Doe, John", "18"`. It needs to be the latter to handle commas in the actual data.

Comment: Yes, colun1,"valor1,valor2,valor3",colun3

Comment: Can you show us the header row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `OPENROWSET`

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Text;Database=C:\;HDR=Yes;FORMAT=Delimited(;)', 'SELECT * FROM [8AA31234-2215-4FE4-907F-AB3B3A417F72~WO2~29302~INSTAL PP~instal pp~1319.csv]')
```

This is a good process to import files with `,` in between the values

Answer (score 0):

You could do a replace during SELECT with Replace:

```
SELECT Replace(fieldWithComma, ',', '') AS fieldWithoutComma
```